# Bootstrap - Fit caption text in thumbnails with fixed height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display bootstrap thumbnails in column with the same height for each. However, the caption text under the image does not fit into the the thumbnail container.

```css
.thumbnail {
    height: 350px;
}
  
img {
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://stephboreldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lorem-ipsum-logo.jpg"><br>
                <div class="caption">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://stephboreldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lorem-ipsum-logo.jpg"><br>
                <div class="caption">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://stephboreldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lorem-ipsum-logo.jpg"><br>
                <div class="caption">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://stephboreldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lorem-ipsum-logo.jpg"><br>
                <div class="caption">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.bootply.com/aPCwXvwXws

Ideally, I would like the text to be displayed with ellipsis when it reach the end of the thumbnail container

Answer (score 1):

if you want the text to be within the borders of thumbnail you can add `display: table;` to you thumbnail div.

If you want to have [multi-line ellipsis](http://daker.me/snippets/truncate-multiline-text-with-ellipsis-in-css.html) like [this demo](https://www.bootply.com/CzFZIqL4UD)
then your css should look like this:

```
.thumbnail {
    height: 350px;
    overflow:hidden;
}    

.caption{
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    line-height: 1.4;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Great! However the ellipsis is not displayed in FF and IE11. Do you know why?

Comment: Hmm, pretty weird, not sure why really. I can see others working in firefox but not this one